# Finding eigenvalues of a 3x3 matrix given determinant and trace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, trace

Suppose a $3×3$ matrix A has only two distinct eigenvalues. Suppose that $\operatorname{tr}(A)=−1$ and $\det(A)=45$. Find the eigenvalues of $A$.

I have solved a similar problem with a 2x2 matrix by using the properties of trace and determinant (trace = a + d and det = ad-bc). I tried to take the same approach for the 3x3 matrix to no success, as expressing the characteristic polynomial is much more complex. Is there any other approach I could take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your eigenvalues are $x$ and $y$.
your matrix $A$ is similar to a diagonal matrix $B$ which has it's eigenvalues on its diagonal.
Now, similar matrices have the same determinant and the same trace, thus we can get to the following equations:
$$2x+y = -1$$
$$x^2y=45$$
The first one is the sum of the diagonal (we know that there are 2 unique eigenvalues thus, one of them will show up 2 times on the diagonal).
The second one is the product of the diagonal (determinant of diagonal matrix).
$$... y=\frac{45}{x^2}$$
$$... x=-3 \space\space\space$$

if $x=-3 => y=5$
$x^2y=45$ and $2x+y=-1$.
And that's our answer :)

Comment: I see how to get from your system of equations to $45+x^2+2x^3=0$. I am not sure where does $x=\frac54$ come from. WA returns [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2x%2By%3D-1%2C+x%5E2y%3D45) for the system of questions and [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=45%2Bx%5E2%2B2x%5E3%3D0) for the cubic equation.

Comment: Why is $A$ diagonalizable ??

Answer (score 0):

There holds for a matrix $A$ that
$$
\sum_i \lambda_i = \operatorname{tr}(A),
\quad
\prod_i \lambda_i = \det(A)
$$
Since you have one eigenvalue twice (i assume $\lambda_1$) this results in:
$$
2 \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = -1,
\quad
\lambda_1^2 \cdot \lambda_2 = 45
$$

// Edit: corrected result:
You can solve this and get to:

$\lambda_1 = -3, \quad \lambda_2 = 5$